# Netbeans JavaDB Bulk import data from CSV file

Tags: sql, netbeans, import, bulkinsert, javadb

I'm really frustrated with JavaDB and Netbeans! ANY help would now be appreciated. I use Netbeans 7.2.1 with the latest Java SDK.

**OBJECTIVE:**

Import data in CSV format from file located in C:\ into a JavaDB table named APP.USERS.

**WHAT I'VE DONE:**

I've used the following codes to try and import the data into the table, using the SQL Query utility in Netbeans:

1. CALL function:

`CALL SYSCS_UTIL.SYSCS_IMPORT_TABLE`
`(null, 'USERS',`
`'FIRSTNAME,LASTNAME,USERNAME,PASSWORD,UNIQUENR,MEMBERSINCE,DOB,EMAIL,AWARDPOINTS,USERTYPE',`
`'c:\SQL_APP_USERS', '\n',',','UTF-8',  0);`
`` ` ``
    SELECT * FROM APP.USERS;`

1. The "other" function:

`INSERT INTO`
`APP.USERS(FIRSTNAME,LASTNAME,USERNAME,PASSWORD,UNIQUENR,MEMBERSINCE,DOB,EMAIL,AWARDPOINTS,USERTYPE)`
`VALUES (FROM 'c:\SQL_APP_USERS.txt'`
`WITH`
`(`
`FIELDTERMINATOR = ',',`
`ROWTERMINATOR = '\n'`
`));`
`--Check the content of the table.`
`SELECT * FROM APP.USERS;`

**ISSUES:**

- Reading the Oracle KB docs doesn't help me at all!!! (`http://docs.oracle.com/javadb/10.4.1.3/tools/ctoolsimport16245.html`)
- Executing first mentioned function shows result: `Error code -1, SQL state 42Y03: 'SYSCS_UTIL.SYSCS_IMPORT_DATA' is not recognized as a function or procedure.`
- Executing second mentioned function shows results: `Error code -1, SQL state 42X01: Syntax error: Encountered "FROM" at line 2, column 9`

PLEASE - HELP.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1.) The specified function you give us

`CALL SYSCS_UTIL.SYSCS_IMPORT_TABLE` (...

does not match the error message

`SYSCS_UTIL.SYSCS_IMPORT_DATA` is not recognized as a function or procedure.

2.) The number of values ​​passed does not meet the required.
    There is no overloaded function with 8 parameters.

```
CALL SYSCS_UTIL.SYSCS_IMPORT_TABLE 
   (null,'STAFF','c:\output\myfile.del',';','%',null,0);
     1      2             3              4   5   6   7

CALL SYSCS_UTIL.SYSCS_IMPORT_TABLE 
   (null, 'USERS','FIRSTNAME,...,', 'c:\SQL_APP_USERS', '\n',',','UTF-8', 0);
     1      2             3                  4            5   6     7     8
```

Also the sequence is wrong .
That would mean that each column is a separate line.

```
'\n',','
```

should be

```
',','\n'
```

3.) It would be nice if it were that easy.

```
INSERT INTO ... VALUES (FROM 'c:\SQL_APP_USERS.txt'
```

So here’s a simple Java Utility class that can be used to load CSV file into Database.

[Import CSV into Database example](http://viralpatel.net/blogs/java-load-csv-file-to-database/)

Tested:

- create a empty file `c:\myfile.del`

---

```
CALL SYSCS_UTIL.SYSCS_IMPORT_TABLE 
     (null,'CUSTOMER','c:\myfile.del',';','%',null,0);
```

[image]

Here, with table `FRIENDS` created for test.

[image]

Since file 'c:\myfile.del' is empty, so nothing to do .
NO error : `is not recognized as a function or procedure`

[image]

Comment: Thank you for the solution!! I'm now getting an error: `Error code -1, SQL state XIE0R: Import error on line 1 of file c:\SQL_APP_USERS.csv: Read endOfFile at unexpected place on line 1. 
Error code 99999, SQL state XIE0E: Read endOfFile at unexpected place on line 1.` <br> My csv file looks like `1,John,Doe,john@example.com,helloworld\n2,Jane,Doe,jane@example.com,helloworld2`  where \n refers to a new line in the csv. My sequence is ",","\n". How do I fix this?

Comment: @JohanBrink First : My example works ?? Second : Do not use `\n` it's hard to maintain . The function can not see the difference between the end of a string and a new line ! So please use `%` or any other string delimiter.

Comment: Nevermind, got it working. THANK YOU!!! You just helped a whole IT class overcome a JavaDB issue.

Comment: @moskito-x Could you look at my DB/Eclipse-Hibernate problems, please?
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35834001/duplicate-schema-name-in-sequece-generation and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36024747/how-to-create-a-derby-user