# How to create a derby user

Tags: database-schema, derby, creation

I tried to set the DB schema name by schema.xml but it caused a schema name duplication in the generated SQL statement for ID generators. ([Duplicate schema name in sequece generation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35834001/duplicate-schema-name-in-sequece-generation))

I read the schema is defined by the passed user at connection time. Now I would like to set the schema by this way.

But I don't know how can I create a new Derby user and link it with the desired schema. Can somebody help me?

Environment: NetBeans, Glassfish, Derby

I have found this:

```
CALL SYSCS_UTIL.SYSCS_CREATE_USER('username', 'password')
```

But Derby answers:

```
Error code -1, SQL state 42Y03: 'SYSCS_UTIL.SYSCS_CREATE_USER' is not recognized as a function or procedure.
```

Why? I have connected to the db as the default admin user.

Or if I try to dispatch this command from a GUI tool, Derby says:

```
[Error Code: 0, SQL State: 42Y07] : Schema 'SYSCS_UTIL' does not exist
```

Comment: Have you enabled authentication and authorization? If not, you don't have to explicitly create Derby users. Here's some docs: https://db.apache.org/derby/docs/10.12/security/cseccsecure42374.html and https://db.apache.org/derby/docs/10.12/security/cseccsecurenativeauth.html

Comment: I just installed NetBeans with default admin user and try to execute some sql commands in it (there is an "Execute command" tool if you right click on an connection). Because there is just one user in Derby so the principles must match to this (administrator) user.

Comment: The stange is that if I open the tree view of the connection which is used by my app then the default schema (appear in bold) is the one I wish to use. But when I deploy my app, the DS tables created in the admin schema. The deploy tool don't pay any attention to the settings of then connection. Other hand if I use the schema.xml to set the default schema, you know the result (duplicated schema name in id generators).

Comment: Perhaps in your two different configurations (NetBeans versus deployed app) you are connecting as two different users. Instead of trying to set the default schema, does your E/R framework allow you to specify table names in `schema.table` qualified format?

Comment: but there is just the default user : admin. This is my big heartbreak : I'm unable to create a user for the app.

Comment: @Bryan Pendleton How can I enable auths? I'm unable to find the SQL commands.

Answer (score 2):

To Create user in Derby :
I am using Command Line Interface and I have already set my System environment variable to Derby.
Otherwise you can write these command into your CLI

```
java -jar %DERBY_HOME%\lib\derbyrun.jar ij
```

and hit Enter key to run ij tool, and you will see a prompt like this:

```
ij>
```

Now type the following command to create a user (replace sam by the desired username and sampass by the desired password):

```
CALL SYSCS_UTIL.SYSCS_SET_DATABASE_PROPERTY('derby.user.sam','sampass');
```

Now hit enter. This should give a message like this:

```
0 rows inserted/updated/deleted.
```

Answer (score 1):

here is a solution (heavily commented):

```java
String setProperty = "CALL SYSCS_UTIL.SYSCS_SET_DATABASE_PROPERTY(";
String getProperty = "VALUES SYSCS_UTIL.SYSCS_GET_DATABASE_PROPERTY(";
String requireAuth = "'derby.connection.requireAuthentication'";

String sqlAuthorization = "'derby.database.sqlAuthorization'";
String defaultConnMode  = "'derby.database.defaultConnectionMode'";
String fullAccessUsers  = "'derby.database.fullAccessUsers'";

String readOnlyAccessUsers = "'derby.database.readOnlyAccessUsers'";
String provider            = "'derby.authentication.provider'";
String propertiesOnly      = "'derby.database.propertiesOnly'";

System.out.println("Turning on authentication and SQL authorization.");
Statement s = conn.createStatement();

// Set requireAuthentication
s.executeUpdate(setProperty + requireAuth + ", 'true')");

//CALL SYSCS_UTIL.SYSCS_SET_DATABASE_PROPERTY('derby.connection.requireAuthentication','true'
// Set sqlAuthorization

s.executeUpdate(setProperty + sqlAuthorization + ", 'true')");

//CALL SYSCS_UTIL.SYSCS_SET_DATABASE_PROPERTY('derby.database.sqlAuthentication','true'
// Retrieve and display property values

ResultSet rs = s.executeQuery(getProperty + requireAuth + ")");
rs.next();
System.out.println("Value of requireAuthentication is " + rs.getString(1));

rs = s.executeQuery(getProperty + sqlAuthorization + ")");
rs.next();
System.out.println("Value of sqlAuthorization is " + rs.getString(1));

// Set authentication scheme to Derby builtin
s.executeUpdate(setProperty + provider + ", 'BUILTIN')");

// Create some sample users
s.executeUpdate(setProperty + "'derby.user." + txtUname.getText() + "', '" + txtPw1.getText() + "')" );

// Define noAccess as default connection mode
s.executeUpdate(setProperty + defaultConnMode + ", 'noAccess')");

// Confirm default connection mode
rs = s.executeQuery(getProperty + defaultConnMode + ")");
rs.next();
System.out.println("Value of defaultConnectionMode is " + rs.getString(1));

// Define read-write users
s.executeUpdate(setProperty + fullAccessUsers + ", '" + txtUname.getText() + "')");

// Define read-only user
// s.executeUpdate(setProperty + readOnlyAccessUsers + ", 'guest')");

// Confirm full-access users
rs = s.executeQuery(getProperty + fullAccessUsers + ")");
rs.next();
System.out.println("Value of fullAccessUsers is " + rs.getString(1));

// Confirm read-only users
rs = s.executeQuery(getProperty + readOnlyAccessUsers + ")");
rs.next();
System.out.println("Value of readOnlyAccessUsers is " + rs.getString(1));

// We would set the following property to TRUE only when we were
// ready to deploy. Setting it to FALSE means that we can always
// override using system properties if we accidentally paint
// ourselves into a corner.

s.executeUpdate("CALL SYSCS_UTIL.SYSCS_SET_DATABASE_PROPERTY(" + "'derby.database.propertiesOnly', 'false')");
s.close();
```

Let me know if that works (or not) for you.

Comment: You should add text to describe and explain your code, not just throw code badly formatted